# Any way to apply Objective-C category only to current class (or equivalent effect)?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

Let's say I have a custom subclass of UIView called `MyCustomView`. Let's also say that I have a category on UIView called `UIView+Dictionary` that adds an NSDictionary property called `dictionary` to every UIView.

If I were to import `UIView+Dictionary.h` into `MyCustomView.m` then every view referenced within `MyCustomView.m` would have this added `dictionary` property, which in many situations is exactly the desired behavior.

However, if I wanted `UIView+Dictionary` applied only to `MyCustomView` itself and not to every UIView referenced within `MyCustomView.m`, is there a way to do so (or achieve a similar effect)?

I'd like to avoid making `MyCustomView` a subclass of another custom subclass (e.g., `MyViewWithDictionary`), as I'd ideally like to be able to import multiple categories for something akin to multiple inheritance (e.g., `UIView+Dictionary`, `UIView+Border`, `UIView+CustomAnimations`).

In my actual own scenario, I've written a category to automatically implement a custom UINavigationBar in a view controller, but I'd like that category to apply only to the view controller into which I am importing the category and not any other view controllers that may be referenced in that file.

Any and all insights are appreciated! And I apologize in advance as I am fairly certain there are more correct terminologies for the effect described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Josh pointed out, any methods added in categories are basically inert unless you call them. The issue that I was having was for generated properties and swizzled methods in categories (since, as Josh also pointed out, there are no mixins in Objective-C).

I was able to solve this by adding in a custom `BOOL` in my category that defaults to `NO` and acts as a "switch" for whatever category methods and properties I want to specify.

E.g., if I wanted my `dictionary` property to be lazily instantiated but only within `MyCustomView`, I could do the following:

```
// UIView+Dictionary.h

@interface UIView (Dictionary)
@property (nonatomic) BOOL enableDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *dictionary;
@end

// UIView+Dictionary.m

#import "UIViewController+CustomNavigationBar.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIView (Dictionary)

- (void)setEnableDictionary:(BOOL)enableDictionary {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(enableDictionary), @(enableDictionary), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (BOOL)enableDictionary {
    NSNumber *enableDictionaryValue = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(enableDictionary));
    if (enableDictionaryValue) {
        return enableDictionaryValue.boolValue;
    }

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(enableDictionary), @NO, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    return self.enableDictionary;
}

- (void)setDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(dictionary), dictionary, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    if (!self.enableDictionary) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSDictionary *dictionary = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(dictionary));
    if (dictionary) {
        return dictionary;
    }

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(dictionary), @{}, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    return self.dictionary;
}

@end
```

And then within `-[MyCustomView viewDidLoad]` I could simply call `self.enableDictionary = YES`. That way, only instances of MyCustomView will have a non-nil lazily instantiated NSDictionary. (Note that, in this example, all instances of UIViews will still respond to the selector `@selector(dictionary)`, but our behavior will differ based on whether `enableDictionary` is `YES` or `NO`.)

While that is a trivial example, the same strategy can be used for methods that are swizzled within categories. (Again, swizzling methods within categories is probably bad form but a necessary evil in certain scenarios.)

Answer (score 2):

> However, if I wanted UIView+Dictionary applied only to MyCustomView itself [...] is there a way to do so [...]?

Only by changing the category to be on MyCustomView and not UIView.

The header has nothing to do with whether the category's methods are *present* on any given instance. If the category is compiled into your program, the methods are there, no matter where the instance is created. This is the reason that prefixes are so important on methods that are added to framework classes: categories have global effect, and name collisions are undefined behavior.

The header only affects the visibility of the methods as far as the compiler is concerned. You can use the usual tricks to call them at runtime regardless.

The category takes effect on the *class itself*, when the runtime is initialized at launch. If you want the methods of the category to be available only on a certain class, the category must be defined on that class.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected. I guess I have to copy-paste the entire category implementation for each specific class then where I want it applied? E.g., if I have `MyUIViewSubclassOne` and `MyUIViewSubclassTwo` (since categories are not inheritable AFAIK).

Comment: Yeah, there's no mixins in ObjC, so if you can't identify a single superclass to put the category on you'll have to explicitly add it to all of them. However, it's possible to define the methods only in one place and add them to your classes using the runtime library. I also wonder why it's important that these methods _not_ be on UIView: they're basically inert unless you specifically use them. Although they exist, nothing but your code knows that.

Comment: Method swizzling x_x

Comment: Not swizzling; you're not replacing an existing method, just adding methods that nothing else knows about and therefore won't call. It's a little roundabout, because you would still need the header, and then you'd have to tell Clang to not warn you about those not being implemented at compile time. But then you don't have to copy-paste,

Comment: Sorry, I meant: In my particular (actual) category-in-question I am swizzling methods in order to achieve my desired effect entirely within the category implementation (so that the base class can be fully agnostic other than to import the category). I'm fairly certain that swizzling within categories is very bad form. A workaround could be to add in a BOOL in the category that must be set to YES in order for the swizzled method to execute – this too however seems not great.

Comment: Oh! Then, yes, I agree with your emoticon! :)